# Different publickeytoken for the same assembly

Tags: c#, .net, ssis, .net-assembly

I have an assembly that is registered in GAC. In 'Windows/assembly' folder I can see it and also see its PublicKeyToken 'aaaa'. I have a SSIS solution (I think no matter at all what is the type of solution).

SSIS package has many c# scripts, each of them has its own references. Some of them contains reference for my assembly. I see the same path to the assembly in properties for it in each script. BUT one of the scripts has another PublicKeyToken 'bbbb' (the others have 'aaaa'). And it breaks the whole solution. Build works good, but Run fails. How can I manage such situation? 
Update: issue appeared after new version of assembly has been added to the GAC. the old one has been deleted.

I tryed to change reference for a copy of dll but the problem doesn't go away. Maybe is there any way to set PublicKeyToken? I've even tryed to change compiled file (but what if? =))

In .dtsx file (file for compiled package) it looks like:

for one script:

```
<Reference Include="MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,    PublicKeyToken=bbbb, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>C:\assembly.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

for the others:

```
<Reference Include="MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,    PublicKeyToken=aaaa, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>C:\assembly.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: are you sure its the same item that's being referenced?

Comment: @SimonPrice yes